# AsyncTask status doesn't state to FINISHED

Tags: java, android, mobile

The problem:
AsyncTask status doesn't state to FINISHED but remains RUNNING after executing a code in doInBackground() (the application works slowly after starting this task, it is very longtime)

I need FINISHED. What did I do wrong?

Thanks

The code (shortend):

```
    MyTask mt;

    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        int myProgressCount;



        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
               super.onPreExecute();

               Toast.makeText(DeviceUARTContext, "onPreExecute Start Progress Bar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }       

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                // the code of a task

            return null;
        }



        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                Toast.makeText(DeviceUARTContext, "onPostExecute End Progress Bar",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



               Toast.makeText(DeviceUARTContext, "asynctask status: "+mt.getStatus(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // here mt.getStatus() should be "Finished"


        }
 }





ReadDataBut = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button12);
    ReadDataBut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mt = new MyTask();
            mt.execute();

        }
    });
```

Comment: You're asking about why your code keeps running but you're not showing the code...

Answer (score -1):

```
   protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            Toast.makeText(DeviceUARTContext, "onPostExecute End Progress Bar",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



           Toast.makeText(DeviceUARTContext, "asynctask status: "+mt.getStatus(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // здесь mt.getStatus() должно быть "Finished"


    }
```

if your toast "asynctask status:" is being diplayed that means you are already in onPostExecute() i.e your doInBackground() methd has finished and it will finish after this toast is displayed i.e when you onPostExecute() method has finished execution.

See this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.Status.html

It states clearly after the onPostExecuted() has finished its execution status in changed and you are showing toast in the same method before it is finished and thus RUNNING is returned as onPostExecuted() has not finished.

Comment: but mt.getStatus() is "Running" - it means that the task has not executed.

Comment: Nope! task keep in "Running"